# extract strings matching a regular expression vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

i have a text like following

```
1.
2.
3.
4. Test data 1
Please identify the ID number:
# 1016108
Please check if the number above matches the number below. The comparison result
should be "True or False". You should only compare the 7 digits:
a. #1016108
Please try to compare the results from Google OCR Engine and Microsoft OCR Engine.
And choose the one that suits for this task better.
Here is a third number # 123456, please DO NOT use this number for this task
```

i need to extract the numbers which are followed by # alone but not the third number as there is a text "third number" infront of it. also it is mentioned that i should not take this number for matching. so i need to extract first 2 numbers(only numbers) and match and say the result .

Code from Comment

```
Dim mc As MatchCollection
Dim i As Int32
mc = Regex.Matches(txt, "[#]([0-9]+)")
Dim results(mc.Count - 1) As String
For i = 0 To results.Length - 1
    results(i) = mc(i).Value
Next
MessageBox.Show(results.ElementAt(0).ToString)
```

Comment: Please explicitly tell us what the matches are.  I am seeing multiple "numbers" with text in front of them.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Is there any particular error you're encountering?

Comment: Dim mc As MatchCollection
 dim i as Int32
    mc = Regex.Matches(txt,"[#]([0-9]+)")
 
    Dim results(mc.Count - 1) As String
    For i = 0 To results.Length - 1
        results(i) = mc(i).Value
    Next
 system.Windows.MessageBox.Show(results.ElementAt(0).ToString)

Comment: above code extract only the second match coz in the other matches there is a space between  # and the numbers

Comment: there are totally three matches that falls under the criteria of # followed by numbers. out of which i need to  take only the first two .

Comment: @SeetharamanK Why dont u stop the loop after two matches and you can take first two numbers using .*?(?:#\s?([\d]+)) ( https://regex101.com/r/R0Rpt0/1 )

Comment: Are you sure there will be a new line after the numbers following the "#" that you want to use?
eg there is a new line after # 1016108 and #1016108

If so you can use the regex :  #(.*\n)

Comment: @SeetharamanK Is it true that you always only want to extract the first two 7 digit numbers?

Comment: You have no *numbers which are followed by #* in your post. You have several examples of *# followed by a number*, but not one *number followed by a #*.

Answer (score 0):

What you might do is match what you do not want and capture in a group what you do want using [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). Your value will be in captured group 1.

[`\bthird number\s*\#\s*\d+\b|#\s*(\d+)\b`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbthird+number%5cs*%5c%23%5cs*%5cd%2b%5cb%7c%23%5cs*%28%5cd%2b%29%5cb&i=1.%0d%0a2.%0d%0a3.%0d%0a4.+Test+data+1%0d%0aPlease+identify+the+ID+number%3a%0d%0a%23+1016108%0d%0aPlease+check+if+the+number+above+matches+the+number+below.+The+comparison+result%0d%0ashould+be+%22True+or+False%22.+You+should+only+compare+the+7+digits%3a%0d%0aa.+%231016108%0d%0aPlease+try+to+compare+the+results+from+Google+OCR+Engine+and+Microsoft+OCR+Engine.%0d%0aAnd+choose+the+one+that+suits+for+this+task+better.%0d%0aHere+is+a+third+number+%23+123456%2c+please+DO+NOT+use+this+number+for+this+task)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/JTZM68211)

**Explanation**

- `\bthird number\s*\#\s*\d+\b` Match `third number` preceded by a word boundary `\b` to make sure third is not part of a longer match, followed by `#` between zero or more whitespace characters `\s*`
- `|` Or
- `#\s*(\d+)\b` Match `#`, zero or more whitespace characters and capture in a group one or more digits `\d+` followed by a word boundary

Or you might use a positive and a negative lookbehind to assert that what is on the left side is not third number:

[`(?<!\bthird number\s*#\s*)(?<=#\s*)\d+\b`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cbthird+number%5cs*%23%5cs*%29%28%3f%3c%3d%23%5cs*%29%5cd%2b%5cb&i=1.%0d%0a2.%0d%0a3.%0d%0a4.+Test+data+1%0d%0aPlease+identify+the+ID+number%3a%0d%0a%23+1016108%0d%0aPlease+check+if+the+number+above+matches+the+number+below.+The+comparison+result%0d%0ashould+be+%22True+or+False%22.+You+should+only+compare+the+7+digits%3a%0d%0aa.+%231016108%0d%0aPlease+try+to+compare+the+results+from+Google+OCR+Engine+and+Microsoft+OCR+Engine.%0d%0aAnd+choose+the+one+that+suits+for+this+task+better.%0d%0aHere+is+a+third+number+%23+123456%2c+please+DO+NOT+use+this+number+for+this+task)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/JAL36023)

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\bthird number\s*#\s*)` Assert that what is on the left is not `third number` preceded by a word boundary `\b` to make sure third is not part of a longer match, followed by `#` between zero or more whitespace characters `\s*`
- `(?<=#\s*)` Assert that what is on the left side is `#` followed by zero or more whitespace characters
- `\d+\b` Match one or more digits followed by a word boundary

Instead of matching `third` only, you might use `\S+ number` instead of `\bthird number` to match one or more times a non-whitespace character.

Comment: this gave the result  perfectly. how ever, what i posted is one input. there are other 5 inputs similar to what i gave, later on i found that in all the 5 inputs third number is been asked to not to match. so what i did is i wrote a simple regex which will exact all the three numbers and match only the first two and ignore the third always!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim mc As system.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection
```

dim i as Int32
    mc = system.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(txt,"^#\s?")

```
Dim results(mc.Count - 1) As String
For i = 0 To results.Length - 1
    results(i) = mc(i).Value

Next
enter code here
```

Comment: mc(0) and mc(1) needed to be compared , MC(2) always will be left out!!

Answer (score -1):

Following your pattern and if I understand you correctly, you only want the numbers following # only if 'third number' is not written before the #

In that case this simple regex should do, check [this](https://regex101.com/r/mZt1yS/1) out

Here is the regex for those who do not want to follow the link: #(.*\n| \s.*\n)

This assumes that the # you want will have a new line at the end as seen from the example text you've posted.

This will also take care of the inconsistency where there can be a space after #

Comment: Hi, if you're going to downvote please state your reason for doing so, so that I can understand and improve. Thanks.

Comment: I ain't down-voter, but I guess that *if I understand you correctly* is what gave you surprise :)

Comment: no, i think what you have understood about the problem is wrong . i wanted all the numbers which is followed by # but i shold not take the third number becasure it is mentioned that i should not take it !!!! but anyway the big deal here is to extract the numbers  after the hash. thats the first challange